# Equivalent to vim's nnoremap?

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, vim-emulation

Just began transitioning from vim to spacemacs and I can't find a way to define keymappings such as this:

`nnoremap N Nzz`

I tried defining it like this:

`define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "N") (kbd "Nzz"))`

... but using the "N" in the right hand side of the mapping causes the following error:

`error "Lisp nesting exceeds 'max-lisp-eval-depth'"`.

Is there a way to define non-recursive keybindings with kbd?

Comment: Do `C-h k` (stands for C-h: help and k: keybinding). Use these functions to bind it to N key, instead the keys itself.

Comment: There is no such thing.  You're generally encouraged to write a command Doing The Right Thing™ and bind it to a key.  Alternatively, advise the command to recenter afterwards...